# Stored Procedures PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures

My Stored Procedure only works on the first iteration. My code:

```
// Display Event
$result = mysql_query("select ....",$connection_mercury);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];

    $provider = $row['name'];

    $details = mysql_query("CALL $my_schema_to_use.getRefId($provider);",$connection);

    while($b_row = mysql_fetch_array($details))
    {
        $details_result = $b_row['age'] . " - " . $b_row['address'];
    }

    echo "<td>$details_result</td><td>$id</td>
}
```

Lets say the outer while loop does 2 loops as expected. But the 'CALL' only returns a value on the first loop every time. The `$details` variable always remains empty for any loop after the first one.

Comment: Every "inner" loop you are overwritting your $details_result variable.
Every "outer" loop you are overwritting your $details variable.

Comment: FYI, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and have been removed in more recent versions of PHP, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I am overwriting the variables but I think that bit is ok because I have the variable value printed before its overwritten. So I think the issue is that the variable $details is not filled on the second iteration of the outer loop. What u think? thanks again for response

Answer (score 0):

$details_result varible are overwritting with inner loop.

```
while($b_row = mysql_fetch_array($details))
    {
        $details_result = $b_row['age'] . " - " . $b_row['address'];
    }
```

Code should be

```
while($b_row = mysql_fetch_array($details))
{
    $details_result[] = $b_row['age'] . " - " . $b_row['address'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
But the issue is:
The inner loop is only executed the first time.
This is because $details is empty for every iteration after the first execution of the CALL.

So i think the issue is before it gets to the inner while loop, what you think?